# Alternative of IF and "OR"

Tags: matlab, if-statement

In this code (`a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j`) are variables):

```
if ( a>b || c>d || e==f || g<h || i!=j )
{
//Some statement; 
}
```

If one condition is true among the five, the `if` will be executed. However, my actual requirement is that if any three or more of these five conditions are true then `if` should be executed.  In the actual code there may be more conditions (10 or more). How can I change the code to set a minimum number of true conditions? I am coding in MATLAB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may sum up results of your comparisons and check sum against some number. For example:

```
if ( (a>b) + (c>d) + (e==f) + (g<h) + (i!=j) >= 3 )
```